# Store data in custom class array in core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an entity in which i have some attributes to which I have pass custom class which store data in an array of that class 
My core data entity looks like this,

[image]

My `NSManangedObject` Class looks like this,

```
extension SingleChat {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SingleChat> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SingleChat>(entityName: "SingleChat")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var roomSID: String?
    @NSManaged public var isGroup: Bool
    @NSManaged public var lastMessage: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastMsgTime: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastMsgTimeActual: String?
    @NSManaged public var profilePic: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastMsgRead: Bool
    @NSManaged public var unReadMsgsCount: Int16
    @NSManaged public var actualNameFor_1_2_1_chat: String?
    @NSManaged public var isNewGroup: Bool
    @NSManaged public var members : [TCHMember]
    @NSManaged public var messages : [TCHMessage]
    @NSManaged public var twChannelObj: TCHChannel?
    @NSManaged public var groupInfo : [String:JSON]?
}
```

This is how i save my data in core data ,

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "SingleChat", in: context!)
        let user = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        for items in dateWiseSortedSingleRooms
        {
            user.setValue(items.name, forKey: "name")
            user.setValue(items.actualNameFor_1_2_1_chat, forKey: "actualNameFor_1_2_1_chat")
            user.setValue(items.isGroup, forKey: "isGroup")
            user.setValue(items.lastMsgRead, forKey: "lastMsgRead")
            user.setValue(items.lastMsgTimeActual, forKey: "lastMsgTimeActual")
            user.setValue(items.lastMessage, forKey: "lastMessage")
            user.setValue(items.lastMsgTime, forKey: "lastMsgTime")
            user.setValue(items.profilePic, forKey: "profilePic")
            user.setValue(items.roomSID, forKey: "roomSID")
            user.setValue(items.isNewGroup, forKey: "isNewGroup")
            user.setValue(items.unReadMsgsCount, forKey: "unReadMsgsCount")
            user.setValue(items.unReadMsgsCount, forKey: "unReadMsgsCount")
            user.setValue(items.members, forKey: "members")
            user.setValue(items.messages, forKey: "messages")
            user.setValue(items.twChannelObj, forKey: "twChannelObj")
        }

        do {
            try context?.save()
            print("Saved successfully.")
        } catch  {
            print("Fail to save")
        }
```

Now when my code execute app crashes at this line,

```
user.setValue(items.members, forKey: "members")
user.setValue(items.messages, forKey: "messages")
```

With error this,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TCHMember encodeWithCoder:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2807a1780

How I can resolve this? and store my custom class array data in it?

Comment: If you recently added new property to your core data structure you need to reinstall the app once.

Comment: No i haven't added new property it is showing me error while saving this line of code,
user.setValue(items.members, forKey: "members"). @DharmeshKheni

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211115/how-do-you-save-a-custom-class-as-an-attribute-of-a-coredata-entity-in-swift-3

Comment: My TCHMember AND TCHMessage class is basically twilio classes with base class of NSObject, now how i can set there encoder? @DharmeshKheni

Comment: May be you can add encoder to their class?

Comment: This is what it shows when i Jump to their definition, 
/** Representation of a Member on a chat channel. */
 interface TCHMember : NSObject . 
I can't add encoder to their class. @DharmeshKheni

Comment: The error is pretty clear: Both classes `TCHMember` and `TCHMessage` must adopt `NSCoding` as I already said in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628168/nsmanaged-property-cannot-have-an-initial-value). Why don't you use entities instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store non-standard objects in core data, the corresponding attribute is of type `transformable`, so that it can be converted to `NSData` and back.
This can be done if the object adopts the [NSCoding protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding), which requires to implement the functions `encode(with:)` and `init(coder:)` (described there). These functions define which properties of your custom object have to be stored and restored.
An example how to use these functions can be found [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3111-nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data).

**EDIT:**

There is another way to handle transformable attributes: Instead of adopting the `NSCoding` protocol, you could implement your custom `NSValueTransformer`. This class can be implemented independently of your 3rd party classes, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38402028/1987726), and is specified in your core data model, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12649653/1987726). An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33172285/1987726).

**EDIT 2:**

I did not use the 2nd method by myself, but my impression is:
In oder to store a custom object in core data, it must be converted to `NSData`, and during a fetch `NSData` must be converted back to your object.

One way to do so is to use `NSCoding`, but this requires to implement it in the custom class, maybe as an extension. If this is not possible, as in your case, you can implement a custom `NSValueTransformer` object.

For encoding, it is given one of your custom objects as input, and creates as appropriate an `NSData` object from the relevant properties. For decoding, it accepts a `NSData` object, and initialises a new instance of your custom object, and sets these properties.

You just have to specify the name of the `NSValueTransformer` in your core data model, and core data will use this custom `NSValueTransformer`. You can find an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1598600/1987726).

Comment: Thanks for this concise answer, i have one question related to my criteria, i'm converting my attribute "members" to Transformable and passes the the array of [TCHMember] to its custom class. Now TCHMember is a class of third party library twilio. How can i encode it first it and than store data in it? As you can see in above question i'm saving data in that attribute. @Reinhard Männer

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I was not aware that these classes are third party (I regarded twilio as a typo of two). Maybe it is possible to write an extension to these classes in which both functions are declared?

Comment: This  TCHMember  is declared as interface TCHMember : NSObject in TCHMember class of twilio and same TCHMessage. @Reinhard Männer

Comment: I'm passing NSCoder with class of NSManagedObject like this,
@objc(SingleChat)
public class SingleChat: NSManagedObject,NSCoder {
I'm getting an error Multiple inheritance from classes 'NSManagedObject' and 'NSCoder'. Why is this so? @Reinhard Männer

Comment: @Junaid Khan Did you read my edit? I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah i have seen your edited answer and read the given links also, but i didn't get the idea what NSValueTransformer do and how should i pass my custom classes to it and how it will store the value? @Reinhard Männer

Comment: I tried to be more specific. Please see my edit 2 above. Good luck! If you are successful, maybe you can even post your own answer so that others can learn how to do it!